# 'Big shot' scientist offered me collaboration in a meeting. How long before I write to him?

Tags: phd, application, collaboration

I met an important scientist in my field in a scientific meeting last week. We agreed that I should write a project draft and send it to him, so we could set up a collaboration. Because I want to take as much advantage as possible from this opportunity (I am a PhD student), I want to be very careful with the project draft that I sent him. But this week I have been very busy with other work, and I have not been able to write the draft. My fear is that the interaction will 'cool off' as the days past. It's not been a week yet, and I am planning to write this in at most 2 more days. But in general experience, how long is it ok to wait before sending an email like this?

Comment: 5 minutes, but not before he left the table

Answer (score 9):

It will not cool off that quickly. Doing it right is more important than doing it soon.
If you are a PhD student you must talk with your mentor/supervisor before establishing a collaboration or even sending this draft project. You don't know the political background.

Answer (score 3):

This is about a professional relationship; so, as soon as possible you can finish your task, you should send him/her your email.